# SailsJS deployment to Heroku, connect to Mongolabs MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, heroku, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am right now attempting my first Heroku deployment of a SailsJS API. My app uses SailsJS v0.11 and`sails-mongo` 0.11.2.

I have updated `config/connections.js` to include the connection information to  MongoDB database I have hosted for free at [Mongolab](https://mongolab.com/).

```
mongodb: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    url: "mongodb://db-user:password123@ds047812.mongolab.com:47812/testing-db"
}
```

Also updated `config/models.js` to point to that adapter.

```
module.exports.models = {
    connection: 'mongodb',
    migrate: 'safe'
};
```

This is basically all I have changed from running the code locally, when I deploy to Heroku the app crashes and I get this error...

```
/home/zacharyhustles/smallChangeAPI/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:186
      throw err;
            ^
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
2015-07-08T19:37:00.778316+00:00 app[web.1]:     
at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

How do I get rid of this, and make sure Sails does not try connecting to localhost db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was with storing sessions.

My solution was to setup a Redis database to store sessions.

In `config/sessions.js` make sure everything is commented out except for the method you want for session store.

Mine looked like this:

```
adapter: 'redis',
host: 'example.redistogo.com',
port: 1111,
db: '/redistogo',
pass: 'XXXXXYYYYYYXYXYXYYX',
```

This solved my posted problem, hope this helps another person out.

Comment: Thanks much, i try if many ways thinking that this error was causing because sails-mongo was not using the production config options but is sessions, thanks much, help a lot.